# Not able to check map condition in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, code, business-logic

I have a requirement where on Update of account I need to check case if contactId is present and if that contacts Account is same as Case accountId then need to update one field.

I have written some logic but not able to understand how i can check in condition .
Plese suggest
below is my code .this line i am not able to compare.this is wrong i know but not able to find how to resolve
**if(cs.contactId!=null && getCon(accConMap,cs.ContactId))**

```
public class UpdateCaseOnAccoutContact {

public static void updateCaseOnAccCon(list<account>accList) {
    set<id> accids = new set<id>();
    for(account acc:acclist) {
        accids.add(acc.id);
    }
    map<id,list<case>> caseByAccountIdMap = new map<id,list<case>>();
    for(account acc: [select id,(select id,accountId,contactId,AccountContactRelation__c from cases) from account where id in:accIds ]) {
        list<case>caseList = acc.cases;
        caseByAccountIdMap.put(acc.id,caseList);
    }
    system.debug('caseByAccountIdMap>>'+caseByAccountIdMap);
    Map<id,Id>accountIdByContactIdMap = new map<id,id>();
    for(contact con: [select id,AccountId from contact where accountid in: accIds]) {
        accountIdByContactIdMap.put(con.Id,con.accountId);
        system.debug('sdsa>>'+caseByAccountIdMap.get(con.accountid));
    }
    system.debug('accountIdByContactIdMap>>'+accountIdByContactIdMap);
    list<case>caseUpdate = new list<case>();
    Map<id,Map<id,Id>> caseConMap = new Map<id,Map<id,id>>();
    for(id accId : caseByAccountIdMap.keySet()) {
        for(case cs:caseByAccountIdMap.get(accId)) {
            if(cs.contactId!=null && getCon(accountIdByContactIdMap,cs.ContactId)) {
                cs.AccountContactRelation__c = 'account's Contact '+' & case contact'+cs.ContactId+'are same';      
            }
            caseUpdate.add(cs);
        }
    }
    system.debug('caseUpdate>>'+caseUpdate);
    update caseUpdate;

}
public static boolean getCon(Map<id,Id>accountIdByContactIdMap,id accid) {
   boolean ids = accountIdByContactIdMap.containskey(accId);
    return ids;
}
}
```

Comment: Start by renaming your maps to have clearer names: `caseMap` should be `casesByAccountId`, `accConMap` should be `accountIdByContactId`; etc.  Often, clearer variable names yield insight into solving the problem

Comment: Thanks Cropredy for suggestion .I have updated .Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problems like this, aim to get the database to do as much of the work as possible: it is optimised for that job. Pulling sub-sets of the data out into Apex is likely to run you into record count and CPU usage governor limits especially when queries that are of open ended record count such as your:

```
select id,accountId,contactId,AccountContactRelation__c from cases
```

are involved.

So something like this where all the filtering is done in the database will be a safer approach:

```
// Cases related to a Contact child of one of the supplied Accounts
Case[] cases = [
    select Id, AccountContactRelation__c
    from Case
    where ContactId = (select ContactId from Account where Id in :accountIds]
];

// Update the Case when necessary
Case[] updates = new Case[] {};
for (Case c : cases) {
    String message = String.format(
        'Account\'s Contact & Case Contact {0} are the same',
        new Object[] {c.ContactId}
    );
    if (c.AccountContactRelation__c  != message) {
        c.AccountContactRelation__c = message;
        updates.add(c);
    }
}
update updates;
```

Review the [Relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) that are possible in SOQL.